# how to use calendar in spring boot,

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, calendar

in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testCalendar")
public String testCalendar(Calendar time){

    System.out.println(time == null);

    return "request ok" ;
}
```

and open in browser this url :127.0.0.1:8090/test/testCalendar

it got follwer error msg

`springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.Calendar]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException] with root cause
java.lang.InstantiationException: null
atsun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)`

if i want got calendar with null,how can i do?

i try this

```
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(Calendar.class, new CalendarEditor());
     binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateEditor());
    }
```

but not still not working,please help me.

Comment: how do you send your object from your JSP ?

Comment: provide your CalendarEditor class also

Comment: i use browser request,not form commit..

Comment: CalendarEditor can work in springMVC, but in spring-boot can not  work.

Comment: I suggest you dont want to use a `Calendar`. That class has design problems and is long outdated (and yes, it’s abstract, the message is correct, so you cannot instantiate it). Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or another appropriate class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: it also got exception
`No primary or default constructor found for class java.time.LocalDateTime] `

Answer (score 0):

## `protected`

I suspect the issue is that [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#%3Cinit%3E()) is a `protected` class. So you **cannot instantiate from an unrelated class**. See [this other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33627846/642706).

One alternate route is to use the usual backing-class, [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html).

## java.time

The better solution is to avoid `Calendar` and `GregorianCalendar` altogether. These are terribly designed classes with many flaws. They were supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310, implemented by the *java.time* classes.

### `ZonedDateTime`

The replacement for `GregorianCalendar` is [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

### Lack of no-arg constructor

Note that the *java.time* classes purposely lack public constructors. So that also means a lack of no-arg constructors. Instead they use factory methods such as `ZonedDateTime.now` seen above. As a guide, study the [*java.time* naming conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/overview/naming.html).

If you have a framework needing a no-arg constructor, you will need to find a workaround or accommodation.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: thanks
`ZonedDateTime` is lack of no-arg constructor. and framework can't instantiation it.
i  want find  a way to custom instance `Calendar` method in spring boot.